# Remove Rows With Similar Values in Power BI / Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am working with a data set that has some duplicate rows.  The rows are not straight duplicates, but have a time stamp less than a second apart.  I'd like to remove these duplicates, but the question is how.

My current plan is to add two new columns, which are copies of the time stamp column but one has a second added to it and the other has a second removed from it.  I can then add steps to remove rows which have all other values the same, but have the same time stamp as time stamp plus one or minus one.  Doing one after the other should eliminate duplicates but not remove truly unique rows.

How can I accomplish this in Power Query?

Comment: So "duplicate" rows are going to be less than a second apart. How far apart are "distinct" rows going to be? Is there a lower bound?

Comment: Can you show an example? In power query you can select with `Ctrl` each column that you consider and then remove duplicates on base of those columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your "current plan" approach is good - I would apply that in a separate Query, started "By Reference" to the original - I'd call it something like **Non-duplicated time stamps**.

I would duplicate the original time stamp column and then add the new +/- 1 minute columns. I would use **Unpivot Only Selected Columns** on the 3 added time stamp columns to convert them from columns to rows.  Then I would select the generated **Value** column and apply **Keep Duplicates**.  That will keep just the first row of any duplicates found amongst the 3 time stamps.

Then back in the original query, I would add a **Merge Queries** step to connect it to the **Non-duplicated time stamps** query.  I would match on the original time stamp column, possibly on other columns if required.  The **Join Kind** would be **Left Anti (rows only in first)**.  That should remove your duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I had to **Duplicate** the original query instead of Reference, since it would change the referenced query as soon as I tried to Merge.  Otherwise it's working great!